# When connecting my WiFi, how to open browser automatically?

Tags: linux, authentication, android, hostapd

I made my Linux computer providing WiFi access.
This is only to browse its local website.

As one does for a captive portal, I want to force the browser to display and direct to my homepage :
- you choose my SSID
- you get the page without no further action.

How can I do this ?
I thought of acting like a captive portal, but it seems highly tricky.
My clients are iPad and Android.

Comment: related question: http://superuser.com/questions/326916/can-i-show-a-welcome-splash-page-for-my-ad-hoc-network